# Flexbox Layout needs Improvement

Tags: css, flexbox

I have the following problem with the Flexbox layout.

```
<dl class="address">
    <dt> <span class="jicons-icons"> <img src="https://demo.fastfit360.com/FF/images/warning.png" width="16" height="16"> </span> </dt>
    <dd> <span class="contact-street" > Address <br> </span> </dd>
    <dd> <span class="contact-suburb" > City <br> </span> </dd>
    <dd> <span class="contact-state" > State <br> </span> </dd>
    <dd> <span class="contact-postcode" > Zip-Code <br> </span> </dd>
    <dd> <span class="contact-country" > Country <br> </span> </dd>
    <dt> <span class="jicons-icons" > <img src="https://demo.fastfit360.com/FF/images/warning.png" width="16" height="16"> </span> </dt>
    <dd> <span class="contact-emailto"> <a href="mailto:info@website.com">info@website.com</a> </span> </dd>
    <dt> <span class="jicons-icons"> <img src="https://demo.fastfit360.com/FF/images/warning.png" width="16" height="16"> </span> </dt>
    <dd> <span class="contact-telephone" > phone number </span> </dd>
    <dt> <span class="jicons-icons"> <img src="https://demo.fastfit360.com/FF/images/warning.png" width="16" height="16"> </span> </dt>
    <dd> <span class="contact-fax" > fax number </span> </dd>
    <dt> <span class="jicons-icons"> <img src="https://demo.fastfit360.com/FF/images/warning.png" width="16" height="16"> </span> </dt>
    <dd> <span class="contact-mobile"> mobile number </span> </dd>
    <dt> <span class="jicons-icons"> <img src="https://demo.fastfit360.com/FF/images/warning.png" width="16" height="16"> </span> </dt>
    <dd> <span class="contact-webpage"> <a href="#" target="_blank"> website-link</a> </span> </dd>
</dl>
```

The way I want this to look is:

```
[Image] Address         and right now I have:   [Image] Address 
        Zip-Code City                                   Zip-Code City
        State Country                                   State
[Image] mail                                            Country
[Image] phone                                   [Image] mail
[Image] fax                                     [Image] phone
[Image] mobile                                  [Image] fax
[Image] website                                 [Image] mobile
                                                [Image] website
```

I'm have trouble having Zip-Code & City and State & Country to be on the same line next to each other...

Here is a JSFiddle I made that represents my current status on this part of the code:
https://jsfiddle.net/72qesada/

Important to know is:

- I can not change the html code
- CSS-Selectors have to stay the way they are because it may happen that lets say the state is not provided and thus missing
- I would like to avoid JS-Code (pure CSS is the goal here)

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a solution using flexbox, but float and positioning might do what you need in this case:

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uozz5dwt/3/)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.address {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

dd {
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 40px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

dt {
  float: left;
}

dd+dt {
  clear: both;
}

.contact-postcode,
.contact-country {
  position: absolute;
}

.contact-postcode {
  top: 20px;
}

.contact-country {
  top: 40px;
}

dl.address>dd:first-of-type+dd {
  margin-left: 110px;
}

dl.address>dd:first-of-type+dd+dd+dd+dd {
  margin-left: 80px;
}
```

```html
<dl class="address">
  <dt> <span class="jicons-icons"> <img src="https://demo.fastfit360.com/FF/images/warning.png" width="16" height="16"> </span> </dt>
  <dd> <span class="contact-street"> Address <br> </span> </dd>
  <dd> <span class="contact-suburb"> City <br> </span> </dd>
  <dd> <span class="contact-state"> State <br> </span> </dd>
  <dd> <span class="contact-postcode"> Zip-Code <br> </span> </dd>
  <dd> <span class="contact-country"> Country <br> </span> </dd>
  <dt> <span class="jicons-icons" > <img src="https://demo.fastfit360.com/FF/images/warning.png" width="16" height="16"> </span> </dt>
  <dd> <span class="contact-emailto"> <a href="mailto:info@website.com">info@website.com</a> </span> </dd>
  <dt> <span class="jicons-icons"> <img src="https://demo.fastfit360.com/FF/images/warning.png" width="16" height="16"> </span> </dt>
  <dd> <span class="contact-telephone"> phone number </span> </dd>
  <dt> <span class="jicons-icons"> <img src="https://demo.fastfit360.com/FF/images/warning.png" width="16" height="16"> </span> </dt>
  <dd> <span class="contact-fax"> fax number </span> </dd>
  <dt> <span class="jicons-icons"> <img src="https://demo.fastfit360.com/FF/images/warning.png" width="16" height="16"> </span> </dt>
  <dd> <span class="contact-mobile"> mobile number </span> </dd>
  <dt> <span class="jicons-icons"> <img src="https://demo.fastfit360.com/FF/images/warning.png" width="16" height="16"> </span> </dt>
  <dd> <span class="contact-webpage"> <a href="#" target="_blank"> website-link</a> </span> </dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can do with flexbox below the code

Update css code

```
dl.address > dt {
    margin: 0;
    flex: 0 0 7%;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

dl.address dd {
    margin-left: 0px;
    flex: 0 0 93%;
}
```

```css
    * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.address {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
}

dl.address > dt {
    margin: 0;
    flex: 0 0 7%;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

dl.address dd {
    margin-left: 0px;
    flex: 0 0 93%;
}

dl.address > dt:first-of-type,
dl.address > dd:first-of-type {
    order: 1;
}

dl.address > dd:first-of-type + dd + dd + dd {
    order: 2;
    width: auto;
    margin-left: 7%;
}

dl.address > dd:first-of-type + dd {
    order: 3;
    width: auto;
    margin-left: 7%;
}

dl.address > dd:first-of-type + dd + dd {
    margin-left: 7%;
    order: 4;
}

dl.address > dd:first-of-type + dd + dd + dd + dd {
    order: 5;
    margin-left: 7%;
}

dl.address > dt:nth-of-type(2),
dl.address > dt:nth-of-type(2) + dd {
    order: 6;
}

/* Mail */
dl.address > dt:nth-of-type(3),
dl.address > dt:nth-of-type(3) + dd {
    order: 7;
}

/* phone */
dl.address > dt:nth-of-type(4),
dl.address > dt:nth-of-type(4) + dd {
    order: 8;
}

/* Fax */
dl.address > dt:nth-of-type(5),
dl.address > dt:nth-of-type(5) + dd {
    order: 9;
}

/* Mobil */
dl.address > dt:nth-of-type(6),
dl.address > dt:nth-of-type(6) + dd {
    order: 10;
}
```

```html
<dl class="address">
    <dt> <span class="jicons-icons"> <img src="https://demo.fastfit360.com/FF/images/warning.png" width="16" height="16"> </span> </dt>
    <dd> <span class="contact-street" > Address <br> </span> </dd>
    <dd> <span class="contact-suburb" > City <br> </span> </dd>
    <dd> <span class="contact-state" > State <br> </span> </dd>
    <dd> <span class="contact-postcode" > Zip-Code <br> </span> </dd>
    <dd> <span class="contact-country" > Country <br> </span> </dd>
    <dt> <span class="jicons-icons" > <img src="https://demo.fastfit360.com/FF/images/warning.png" width="16" height="16"> </span> </dt>
    <dd> <span class="contact-emailto"> <a href="mailto:info@website.com">info@website.com</a> </span> </dd>
    <dt> <span class="jicons-icons"> <img src="https://demo.fastfit360.com/FF/images/warning.png" width="16" height="16"> </span> </dt>
    <dd> <span class="contact-telephone" > phone number </span> </dd>
    <dt> <span class="jicons-icons"> <img src="https://demo.fastfit360.com/FF/images/warning.png" width="16" height="16"> </span> </dt>
    <dd> <span class="contact-fax" > fax number </span> </dd>
    <dt> <span class="jicons-icons"> <img src="https://demo.fastfit360.com/FF/images/warning.png" width="16" height="16"> </span> </dt>
    <dd> <span class="contact-mobile"> mobile number </span> </dd>
    <dt> <span class="jicons-icons"> <img src="https://demo.fastfit360.com/FF/images/warning.png" width="16" height="16"> </span> </dt>
    <dd> <span class="contact-webpage"> <a href="#" target="_blank"> website-link</a> </span> </dd>
</dl>
```